# Call original function after hooked function

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, hook

I want to learn how to make hooks so I made a simple program to test me. The hook is working perfectly but I also wanted to call the original function after calling the hooked. Tried to do in many ways, moving the stack, restoring the original bytes and then calling the original function at the end of the hooked function but it did not work.

My program simply waits any key and print the text.

My hook (DLL):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void WriteMem(DWORD dwAddr, BYTE *dwNew, int Size);

void MyPrintf(char *text)
{
    printf("\n Original message: %s\n", buff);
}

void WriteMem(DWORD dwAddr, BYTE *dwNew, int Size)
{
    DWORD OldProt;
    VirtualProtect((void*)dwAddr, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProt);
    memset((void*)(dwAddr), 0x90, Size);
    memcpy((void*)(dwAddr), (void*)(dwNew), Size);
    VirtualProtect((void*)(dwAddr), Size, OldProt, &OldProt);
}

void SetJMP(INT32 dwOld, LPVOID dwNew, INT32 Size)
{
    BYTE dwNewBytes[5] = {0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    DWORD calc = ((DWORD)dwNew - dwOld - 5); 
    memcpy(&dwNewBytes[1], &calc, 4);
    WriteMem(dwOld, dwNewBytes, Size);
}

int SetIntercepet()
{   // 0x40102A printf address
    SetJMP(0x40102A, MyPrintf, 7);
    return 0;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        SetIntercepet();           
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

My test program (C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        system("pause");
        printf("ORIGINAL\n");
    }
}
```

part of the test program decompiled:

```
00401000  /$ 55             PUSH EBP
00401001  |. 8BEC           MOV EBP,ESP
00401003  |> B8 01000000    /MOV EAX,1
00401008  |. 85C0           |TEST EAX,EAX
0040100A  |. 74 1C          |JE SHORT test.00401028
0040100C  |. 68 00E04000    |PUSH test.0040E000                      ;  ASCII "pause"
00401011  |. E8 D9000000    |CALL test.004010EF
00401016  |. 83C4 04        |ADD ESP,4
00401019  |. 68 08E04000    |PUSH test.0040E008                      ;  ASCII "ORIGINAL"
0040101E  |. E8 07000000    |CALL test.0040102A
00401023  |. 83C4 04        |ADD ESP,4
00401026  |.^EB DB          \JMP SHORT test.00401003
00401028  |> 5D             POP EBP
00401029  \. C3             RETN

0040102A  /$ 6A 0C          PUSH 0C
0040102C  |. 68 50D44000    PUSH test.0040D450
00401031  |. E8 52140000    CALL test.00402488
00401036  |. 33C0           XOR EAX,EAX
00401038  |. 33F6           XOR ESI,ESI
0040103A  |. 3975 08        CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8],ESI
```

Comment: The location of a function is not guaranteed to be the same between builds. You should address this deficiency before moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are overwriteing the actual printf function, you'll have to copy the instructions there and then perform the relevant "fixup" to make it work in the new location, as well as jumping back to "after your patch". This would either involve knowing exactly what the original code is (in other words, `push 0c, push test.0040d450`), or understanding enough of the machine code to split instructions up on their boundaries.

Another, much easier method would be to replace the original call-spot with new code. So, instead of patching your code into 0x40102a, you patch your code into 40101E, saving the 40102a from the original call point, and once you have done what you need to do, you call back into 40102a.

Something like this would do that:

```
void* origPrintf;

void MyPrintf(char *text)
{
    void (*orig)(char *text) = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(char *text)>(origPrintf);
    printf("\n Original message: %s\n", buff);

    orig(text);
}

void WriteMem(DWORD dwAddr, BYTE *dwNew, int Size, void &*oldCall)
{
    DWORD OldProt;
    int offset;
    VirtualProtect((void*)dwAddr, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProt);
    memcpy(offset, (void*)(dwAddr + 1), sizeof(offset)); 
    oldCall = (void*)dwAddr + 5 + offset;   // 5 byte call instruction assumed.
    memset((void*)(dwAddr), 0x90, Size);
    memcpy((void*)(dwAddr), (void*)(dwNew), Size);
    VirtualProtect((void*)(dwAddr), Size, OldProt, &OldProt);
}

void SetJMP(INT32 dwOld, LPVOID dwNew, INT32 Size, void&*oldCall)
{
    BYTE dwNewBytes[5] = {0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    DWORD calc = ((DWORD)dwNew - dwOld - 5); 
    memcpy(&dwNewBytes[1], &calc, 4);
    WriteMem(dwOld, dwNewBytes, Size, oldCall);
}


int SetIntercepet()
{   // 0x40102A printf address
    SetJMP(0x40102A, MyPrintf, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

[I can't check the code, as I'm pretty sure the addresses are quite different on my 64-bit Linux machine, but it should give a reasonable principle]

Comment: That answer is so bad, and the code is broken everywhere. I know you mention you couldn't check it. But come on general syntax errors `void&*` and `SetJMP(4 parameters)` called `SetJMP(3 arguments)`.

Comment: I fixed the general problems, but it didn't really change anything. This causes an obvious system crash, when trying to call the original function from the hooked function.